# Remove high level savegame

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have a mid-level (TH7) account on an iPad, which I wish to replace with a more developed account from an android phone. However, when I try to transfer the account I am told that my save is too high level to replace (Beyond TH4.)

How can I work around this?

Comment: Wouldn't uninstalling the game and logging with the higher level acc work ?

Comment: No. It syncs to the account as soon as I reinstall, even after logging out of Game Center.

Answer (score 2):

Simply do the following:

1. Delete clash of clans from your device
2. Log out of your game center
3. Re-download COC
4. Sync with the more developed account after completing the tutorial
5. Done. IDK if you can log back into game center at this point.

EDIT: See this for more info:

http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/562925-How-do-I-overwrite-my-account